# Z-Index of banner-rotator Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider, jssor, jquery-ui-slider

I am having some problems with getting the slider to display right. I have it setup and working, however, I need the slider to slide behind my nav bar on the top of my page. It goes right over the top and that prevents the site from being used. Someone please help! I have tried changing z-index to a different number to get this to work. Any ideas?

http://test.mountaintopwebdesign.com/

Comment: it seems to be working fine for me - which browser are you using?

Comment: What about setting `z-index` for the `overHeader`? <div class="overHeader" style="z-index: 2;">

Comment: It was working on Firefox, but not on Chrome! I did that and it worked!